# Generating OL LI tree structure from a recursive call of Java method

Tags: java, recursion

I have list of objects type Node (**items**). And Node class has children in it (**childItems**). I Want to print this structure in ol li html markup.

Preparing in a recursive method. But there is some issue in my logic. Have a look on my code.

The the size of the **items** will be 2. According to given sample markup. Means 2 top level parents exist. And then they have further children as a list in them.

```
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

 void printValues(ArrayList items){ 
for (Object o : items){
    html.append("<ol>");
    html.append("<li>");
    Node node = (Node)o;
    html.append(node.getName);

    if (node.getChildItems()!= null){
        printValues(node.getChildItems());
    }else{
        html.append("</li>");
    }
    html.append("</ol>");
}   
 }
// ...........
 System.out.println(html.toString(););

//...
  public class Node{
String Name;
ArrayList childItems = new ArrayList(); // of type Node
/* getter setters are proper */
}
```

Following markup is an example. It can be on N level.

```
<ol>
<li>
    Manager
    <ol>
        <li>
            Associate Manager
            <ol>
                <li>
                    A.M. Configuration 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    A.M. Configuration 2
                </li>
                <li>
                    Staff Memmber
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            Staff Memmber Configuration
                        </li>
                        <!-- can goes on -->
                        <li>...</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>
    Client Package
    <ol>
        <li>
            Gold
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Feature 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Feature 2
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: Split your function in two, one that does li, the other ol, and call from each other. Will be much more clear what is going on

Comment: I am still thinking how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example (my comment about functions calling each other):

```
public class LiOl {
  static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  static void printList(List<Node> l) {
    if (l == null || l.size() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    sb.append("<ol>");
    for (Node n : l) {
      printNode(n);
    }
    sb.append("</ol>");
  }

  static void printNode(Node n) {
    sb.append("<li>").append(n.name).append("</li>");

    sb.append("<li>");
    printList(n.children);
    sb.append("</li>");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Node> l = null;
    printList(l);

    sb.toString();
  }
}

class Node {
  String name;
  List<Node> children;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part should be worked over:

```
...
html.append("<li>");    
Node node = (Node)o;    
html.append(node.getName);    
if (node.getChildItems()!= null){        
  printValues(node.getChildItems());    
}else{
  html.append("</li>");    
}
...
```

you'll see what I mean when we reduce it more to

```
...
html.append("<li>");    
...
if (node.getChildItems()!= null){        
  ...    
}else{
  html.append("</li>");    
}
...
```

Comment: Look at the opening li tag and the close tag. If you open the li you have to close it ALWAYS, but does your if condition fullfill the closing tag always? Do you see it?